# Get Javascript view of file tree from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, directory-tree

I'm building a site in which I need to show the users a Directory and file tree so they can get access to files that directed to the page subject.

right now my site is hosted on my Windows 2008 R2 Server, and I need the file tree to come from another storage in my network, so I've created a Virtual Directory on my IIS server that is linked to this storage, but now I face another problem, how to show the user a file tree from a URL and not a path on the server?

I use this JS file tree : http://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree/

when I wanted to show files from within the server the 'root' was something like this: "../../files/page1"
and it worked.

but now the 'root' is : "mysite.org/virtualDirectoryToStorage/files/page1"
and it doesn't work.

any idea how I can use URL as a path to this code?
or another way to map the storage on my server so it will work as path?
or other JS file tree to use?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move the connector script to the second server (the one that you are trying to traverse and has the files).

Then in your File Tree root code, you have to change the `root` to the path of the connector on the new server.

I haven't reviewed the connector script, but you may also  have to enable CORS in the connector script as now the paths are different.

Php would do it as such:

```
 <?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 ?>
```